# View and Submit entries in batches/slots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am designing a rails application in which there is model named race_timing which store the timings of students participate in different events.On view page names of student according to selected event and age group is displayed for entering the time taken by each individual to complete the race.Currently I am storing the student_id and their corresponding timing in an array as I want to submit multiple entries on single submit and it is working properly.
But now I want to display only 8 students at a time from the array and store their corresponding timings  but i am not getting a proper way to do so.
Can anyone suggest some solution??

race_timing_controller

```
@mid = MemberEvent.where("event_id IN (?)", params[:race_timing_ind_evnt][:event_id]).pluck(:member_id)
#@mid=MemberEvents.find_by_event_id(params[:event_id]).pluck(:member_id)
@midlst=Member.where("id IN (?) AND competetion_level_id IN (?)",@mid,params[:race_timing_ind_evnt][:age]).pluck(:id)
#@meid=MemberEvent.where(@mname.id).pluck(:id)
@mname=[]
@midlst.each do |i|
  @fmn=Member.where("id IN (?)", i).pluck( :name)
  @mname.push(@fmn).flatten!
end
@race_timing_ind_evnt = RaceTimingIndEvnt.new
```

race_timing_view

```
<% @mname.zip(@midlst).each do |mn,i| %> 

        <tr>
            <td><%= mn %></td>
            <%= hidden_field_tag "member_id[]",i%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, :value => params[:race_timing_ind_evnt][:event_id]%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :age_group, :value => params[:race_timing_ind_evnt][:age]%>
            <td><%=text_field_tag "mem[]"%></td>
            <td><%= check_box_tag("", "", true, class: "checkbox") %></td>
        </tr>
       <% end %>
```

Comment: Have you considered using JQuery DataTables? You can page the rows of your table in chunks. By default, it can show 10, 25, 50 or 100 rows at a time, but you can override that behavior to display 8 as per your requirements.

Comment: Off topic, but your class and controller name should adhere to CamelCase per ruby naming conventions.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Jquery data tables is only for restricting the view but I want to submit the entries i.e. timing of students in slots of 8 which is stored in an array "mem[]"